# How does AWS Pinpoint behave when push notification `ChannelType` is set to `PUSH`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm evaluating AWS Pinpoint to send push notifications.

In the [reference document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-messages.html#apps-application-id-messages-model-apnsmessage) it states that `ChannelType` can be one of:

```
PUSH | GCM | APNS | APNS_SANDBOX | APNS_VOIP | APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX | ADM | SMS | VOICE | EMAIL | BAIDU | CUSTOM | IN_APP
```

However I was unable to find documentation on **what happens when I use the value `PUSH`?**

I have a sandbox iOS app set up, and if I register the endpoint as `APNS_SANDBOX` and send a message, it works. If I change to `PUSH`, register that, and send a message with channel type `PUSH`:

```
{
    "MessageConfiguration": {
        "DefaultPushNotificationMessage": {
            "Body": "Hello world",
            "Title": "Test title",
            "Action": "OPEN_APP",
            "SilentPush": false
        }
    },
    "Addresses": {
        "...token...": {
            "ChannelType": "PUSH"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error response:

```
{
    "Message": "No Addresses or Endpoints to send to"
}
```

If I use the GET Endpoint API, I do see my endpoint registered there as a `PUSH` address:

```
{
    "ChannelType": "PUSH",
    "Address": "...token...",
    "EndpointStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "OptOut": "NONE",
    "RequestId": "...",
    "EffectiveDate": "2021-08-09T08:57:08.832Z",
    "ApplicationId": "...",
    "Id": "...",
    "CohortId": "51",
    "CreationDate": "2021-07-28T07:56:22.074Z"
}
```

I get the same error message if I register the endpoint as `APNS_SANDBOX` and use `PUSH` in SendMessage.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the aws docs regarding `PUSH` channel you have to be specific,
You can use the `user.id` something like this:

```
message_request = {
                "MessageConfiguration": {
                    "APNSMessage":
                    {
                        "Action": "OPEN_APP",
                        "RawContent":raw_message_ios

                    },
                    "GCMMessage": {
                        "Action": "OPEN_APP",
                        "RawContent":raw_message_android
                        #"{\"notification\": {\"title\": \"Hello Android World!\",\"body\":\"From PinPoint CLI\"},\"data\":{\"custom\":\"123 Penny Lane\"}}"
                    },
                },
                "Users": {
                    user:{
                        'TitleOverride': ""
                    }
                }
            }
```

I use this with `send_users_messages`

```
response = self.client.send_users_messages(
                    ApplicationId=self.application_id,
                    SendUsersMessageRequest=message_request
                )
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to send push notifications, but the docs _do_ mention PUSH as a possible channel type, and my question is about what happens when that is used? See [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-messages.html#apps-application-id-messages-model-apnsmessage) under AddressConfiguration / ChannelType / Values: `PUSH | GCM | APNS | APNS_SANDBOX | ...`